# Saving Illustrator AI File as PDF and PDF is inaccurate

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, layers

[image]I created a wireframe in Illustrator. I have it saved as an AI file. I decided to "Save As" a PDF so as to send it to the client. The PDF shows excess footer layers at the bottom. In fact, it replicated my footer two more times. I did not name my layers and I cannot find where to delete this is in the AI file version of the wireframe, because the excess footers do not show up here. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: It's kinda hard to say without seeing at least a screenshot of the document in AI and in Acrobat or wherever you preview the PDF. That might not be enough to say for sure, but it would be a start. Right now I can't even make a guess other than: "it must be there somewhere if it shows up in the pdf".

Comment: Edited to include screenshot.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not enough. Perhaps if you add a screenshot of the pdf as well. I can see the footer is there, but I can't see the excess since it shows up in the pdf, as you said. I was thinking it might be just bleeds revealing extra graphics from the paste board, but it doesn't seem like it right now. — You could also maybe try to use Direct selection tool to select the visible graphics and paste them to a new document and see what happens when you export that as pdf.

Comment: Not possible to answer. In 25+ years I've never seen merely saving an .ai file as a PDF cause random content to be duplicated in the PDF.

Comment: Thank you. I will try the direct selection tool. I uploaded a jpeg of the PDF.

Comment: Do you have multiple artboards in Illustrator? Like some mistaken duplication of artboards for the footer?

Comment: I do have multiple artboards, but only one for this project. I DID take the footer from another artboard. It was a website footer template.

Answer (score 2):

Each artboard in Illustrator will create a page in a PDF (even if artboards overlap).

It appears as though you have 3 artboards.... one full size, then 2 the size of the footer.

Delete the extra 2 footer artboards and then save as a PDF again, you should have only 1 page. Or you could merely delete the extra 2 pages in the PDF using Acrobat.